# How to access librdkafka.redist logs from C# application which uses it as a dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

My application console log shows a lot of the following:

```
%3|1602097315.970|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap]: kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 42ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1602097315.970|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-3| [thrd:kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap]: kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 41ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1602097315.972|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kfkqaapq0003d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap]: kfkqaapq0003d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0003d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 48ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1602097315.973|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: kfkqaapq0003d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0003d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 48ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1602097316.459|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kfkqaapq0001d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap]: kfkqaapq0001d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0001d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 42ms in state CONNECT)
```

None of this appears in the application log file.

My application was developed in C# and has `Confluent.Kafka` as a dependency which uses `librdkafka.redist`. I assume that's where it's coming from. I'm looking into the possibility that they're related to the heartbeat.

My appSettings.json has the following logging config:

```json
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
  },
  "FileTargetPath": "./Logs",
  "FileTargetName": "My.Application"
},
```

Is this also written to a log file anywhere or is there any way I could parse it from a .NET Core Healthcheck in my application?

Comment: can you include your logging configuration?

Comment: I added the logging config. Is it possible the lines I'm querying relate to Kafka heartbeat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass your own log handler to the client builder, see
https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.ProducerBuilder-2.html#Confluent_Kafka_ProducerBuilder_2_SetLogHandler_System_Action_Confluent_Kafka_IProducer__0__1__Confluent_Kafka_LogMessage__

E.g.:

```cs
           using (var producer =
                new ProducerBuilder<byte[], byte[]>(producerConfig)
                    .SetLogHandler((_, m) => ..emit m as you wish..)
                    .Build())
```